# How to center align multiple items in same row within relative layout

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

Is it possible to center align these two items horizontally together without using 1 table row? These items are within a relative layout.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_warning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_warning"
        android:padding="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="message"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_warning" />
```

Comment: post your code..

Comment: @Dus code was there, but didn't appear for some reason

Comment: setting android:layout_centerVertical="true" on both views didn't help ?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: What if you put the two items in a linearLayout and then set the gravity center horizontal?

Comment: I added the answer. please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "drawableLeft" and remove the imageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/stat_sys_warning"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="message" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you put the two items in a linearLayout and then set the gravity center horizontal?